# trouble sending emails via contact form with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a trouble sending e-mails with the PHPMailer class, after I have submitted the form,  this message show up : "message sent" but I don't receive any emails and I have even checked the spam folder and its empty.

here is the html form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">

<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">

<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="7" name="message">    </textarea>

<input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

and the php code is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

     if(isset($_POST['subject'])){ $subject = $_POST['subject']; }
     if(isset($_POST['message'])){ $message = $_POST['message']; }
     if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }
     if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = $_POST['email']; }

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); 

$body             = $message;

$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);

$address = "example@domain.net";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "example@domain.net");

$mail->Subject    = $subject;

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I suggest you check your SMTP configurations. Do you have a valid SMTP setting for an email server? From your codes, you are not using any SMTP server to send emails. So the emails will not be sent even though your code is correct and success is returned.

Comment: When left unconfigured (no SMTP relay), PHPMailer uses the same transport as the `mail()` function. The same conditions therefore apply. Enable debugging, check the logs, DKIM/SPF, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and suggestions, i have edited the php code and add smtp configurations with smtp auth disabled cause the domain doesnt need authentication but the problem still the same......

Comment: are you definitely sending to a valid address? There could be all sorts of reasons a mail fails to be delivered - spam filters, network errors along the route to name a couple. Just because the code thinks it's sent an email doesn't guarantee the email will arrive at its destination.

Comment: You should be using a more recent PHPMailer version using the `Autoload` feature.

Comment: here is the edit and and the error message is "Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found"
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your html code**

```
<form action="yourphpcode.php" method="post">

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">

<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">

<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="7" name="message">    </textarea>

<input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

**here is your php code**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $subject = "subject : " . $_POST['subject'] . "<br>";
    $message = "message :" . $_POST['message'] . "<br>";
    $name    = "name :" . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";
    $email   = "email :" . $_POST['email'] . "<br>";

    $message = "
 \n $subject \n 
 \n $message \n  
 \n $name \n 
 \n $email \n 

";
    echo $message;

    include "PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'yourgmail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password   = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('someaddress@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('someaddress@example.com', 'Test Name');
    $mail->addAttachment('fileaddress');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}

?>
```

**try this working fine..!!**

Comment: thank you, it works fine but the email sender name doesn't appear at the inbox , it show the sender is "Root user" i've try to edit the code like that    $name    = $_POST['name'] ;
    $email   = $_POST['email'] ;    but id didn't work and didn't send the mail

Comment: I'm not getting any root user in my localhost.